# What is the color shift between Alien Bees b800 and Elinchrom Rx 600 lights?

Tags: color-management, studio-lighting, color-correction, elinchrom

I have a shoot coming up at a rental studio where they provide Alien Bees b800(s). To supplement I'm bringing one of my Elinchrom lights for a key. Anyone know what to expect in terms of color shift between the bees and Elinchrom, and how much variation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Paul Buff states that the Alien Bee series has a color temperature of 5600K at full power and a search for the temperature of the Rx600 suggests a 5600K to 5650K +/- 300K. The implies that all are within a basic margin of error.

However, if this is critical work, I would measure the temperature of each of the lights with a grey card. All similar lights exhibit a color shift to some degree as the power is dialed down, but the consensus is that the AB family is especially subject to this. So measuring is probably a really good idea here, especially since these will be fill lights.

One solution is to neutral density filter these lights and keep the ABs at full power if this happens (it may not be an issue).